# How to set current tab of QTabWidget by name?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtabwidget

PyQt5's `QTabWidget` has a method `setCurrentIndex` that you can use to get a particular tab to become the active tab. I can't seem to find any way to index by tab name though (which I set in Qt Designer). Is there any way (either direct or indirect) to index by name instead?

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#currentIndex-prop

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The tab name becomes the object-name of the widget set as the tab's page. When the tab is added, the page will be automatically re-parented to the internal stack-widget of the tab-widget. This means you can get a reference to the page like this:

```
page = tabwidget.findChild(QWidget, tabname)
```

and get its index like this:

```
index = tabwidget.indexOf(page)
```

or set the current tab directly by name like this:

```
tabwidget.setCurrentWidget(tabwidget.findChild(QWidget, tabname))
```

Answer (score 9):

An alternative is to remember the tab's index when adding the tab. Then reuse it later in your code:

```
index = tabWidget.addTab(myWidget)
// ...
tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

Answer (score 7):

A method that given a tab_name returns a list of indices for tabs whose names match the tab_name.

```
def get_indices(tab_name):
    return [index for index in range(tab_widget.count())
        if tab_name == tab_widget.tabText(index)]
```

After finding the index with this function then standard PyQt methods can be used.

**Not the best way to do this**, but might be useful sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `indexOf()` like this :

remove your tab :

```
self.tabWidget.removeTab(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.YOUR_TAB_name))
```

add your tab:

```
self.tabWidget.addTab(self.YOUR_TAB_name, "name"))
```